# update all values in the sub array of one object in mongodb using mongoose

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongoose

`user = {
   'userid':'111',
   'mail':[{
      'time':22222,
      'info':'this is a info1',
      'read':false,
   },{
      'time':33333,
      'info':'this is a info2',
      'read':false,
   }]
}`

then, I want to change one user's read flag to true, how can i do for it ?

Comment: Hi there, welcome to stack overflow. To better get help with your question you will need to show a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you are trying to achieve and expected output. Meaning, what is your code now, what are you trying to do and what is your code doing instead?

Answer (score 0):

here is my answer:

```
        User.update({
            'userid':userid,
            'mails':{
                '$elemMatch':{
                    'read':false
                }
            }
        },{
            '$set':{
                'mail.$.read':false,
                'newmail':0,
            }
        }, { multi: true }, function (err, data) {
            if(err > 0){
                console.log('ReadMail err', err);
            }
        });
```

Comment: ```The positional $ operator acts as a placeholder for the first element that matches the query document```
Source - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#up._S_

Answer (score 0):

here is a simple example: my model is User !! my url is the path to the DB

```
    var newUser = new User();
  newUser.name = request.body.name;
  newUser.email = request.body.email;  
  newUser.pass = request.body.pass;
  newUser.position = request.body.pos;
  newUser.phone = request.body.phone;
mongoose.connection.openUri(url);


  var myquery = { _id : request.params._id };

    console.log("updating...")
    User.findByIdAndUpdate(myquery,{$set: newUser},{new: true},function(err, result) {
      if(err)
      {
       throw err;
      }
      response.json({code: 0 , result});

});
```